# Symfony2 - Undefined property in entity for file upload

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I am getting the following error when trying to upload a file, it's odd because I've used the same code on other projects without any problems/errors.

What am I missing here?

```
Notice: Undefined property: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Article::$file in /var/www/html/InsideFight/src/Acme/DempBundle/Entity/Article.php line 277
```

**The problem line is:**

```
if (null !== $this->file) {
```

I do not have any file upload code in my controller it's being handled in the entity.

**Entity**

```
public $file;


public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'images/';
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->image = uniqid() . '.' . $this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // If there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);

    unset($this->file);
}
/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you do `unset($this->file);`. Change it to `$this->file = null`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I dunno why this didn't work before as I used the same code prior on other projects and it worked fine. Can you explain what was wrong with unset vs. $this->file = null????

Comment: `unset` remove property from object completly so it's becomes undenefined. `$this->file = null` just set it to `null`.

Comment: Right, but this is the exact line I used for previous code, and it works. The same line with unset. Is this something new with the newer version of Symfony2?

Comment: This is just `Notice`. Maybe your php error level on previous app was different (ex: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`).

Comment: Possibly, but nothing was changed as I'm using a virtual box and no settings were changed between projects. Only thing that is different is the Symfony2 versions (2.4 and 2.5) and the fact I didn't use stof using Gedmo (stofdoctrineextentions) for slugs in the previous projects. Using SonataAdminBundle and that notice prevented my new post from being created. Frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Include the following namespace.

```
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
```

Make the file variable private and create a temp file variable.

```
  private $file;
  private $tempFile
```

Then create getter and setter methods for $file.

```
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;

    if (isset($this->image)) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->tempfile = $this->image;
        $this->image = null;
    } else {
        $this->image = 'initial';
    }
}
```

Then, modify preUpload and upload functions.

```
public function upload()
{
     if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);

    // check if we have an old image
    if (isset($this->tempFile)) {
        // delete the old image
        unlink($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->tempFile);

        // clear the temp image path
        $this->tempFile = null;
    }
    $this->file = null;
}



public function preUpload()
{
   if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
        // generate a unique name
        $filename = uniqid();


        $this->image = $filename . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension();


    }
}
```

Comment: Ok tried this and get this error: `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/Article.php line 334` line 334 is `$this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);`

Comment: Change that line to $this->getFile->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);